# Can mod_auth_mellon be used with a load balancer?

Tags: apache, saml-2.0

Can mod_auth_mellon be used by two or more Apache instances behind a load balancer?  If so is there special configuration needed to make the instances share Mellon sessions?

The [only thing I can see](https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon) which may be relevant is discouraging:

> MellonLockFile is the full path to a file used for synchronizing
>   access to the session data. The path should only be used by one
>   instance of apache at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [session affinity / persistence is required](https://sympa.uninett.no/lists/uninett.no/arc/modmellon/2017-03/msg00011.html)

Comment: So does this mean, yes, it can be used, or no, it can't?

Comment: My answer may be out of date, but it means yes you can use it behind a load balancer, but it will need to be configured to send all requests from a given user/session to the same Apache server

Comment: I still don't get it: If it has to be sent to the SAME Apache, it is not working with load balancing, but more with a single web proxy. Load balancing means, a user's request may end up on different Apache servers. And then, I think, the answer to this question should be "No, it doesn't work with load balancing." It would be helpful, if you cleared up the matter or provided a link that works (the above one doesn't for me). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Different users can be sent to different Apache servers, so it is can balance the load across servers = load balancing.  It just doesn't support it very nicely, in that a given user session has to keep being sent to the same server

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Sadly, this is a very restricted form of load balancing that surely won't be possible to fall back on to for a lot of people...

Comment: True, it's undesirable